# Is there at least a continuous curve connecting any two points in a length metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, arc-length

These are three questions about metric spaces with the [intrinsic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric) on them.

Let $(M,d)$ be a length metric space, i.e. its metric is the intrinsic metric.

- Can such a space have a point $p$ whose distance $d(p,q)$ from all other $q \in M$ is not less that some $s > 0$, i.e . a discrete point $p$, which can be isolated by an open ball $B_s(p)$ with $B_s(p) \cap M = \emptyset$ ?
- Does every open ball $B_s(p)$ at $p$ contain a point $q \neq p$ ?
- Can every two points $p,q \in M$ be connected by continuous curve $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$, $\gamma(0) = p, \gamma(1) = q$ ?

The answers to the first and second seem to be no and yes, respectively, because of the property of having approximate midopints (see the Wiki article above). Could anyone confirm and elaborate.

Comment: The intrinsic metric is not well-defined for metric spaces that are not path-connected, so the answer to your first point is no (since a space with an isolated point cannot be path-connected). A metric space with just one point is a length metric space, so the answer to your second point is no.  The third point doesn't really make sense, since the intrinsic metric isn't defined on spaces that aren't path-connected - I'd guess the answer should be yes.

Comment: Please, write in the details the definition of a path metric space you are using.

Comment: PS: my comment above assumes the standard convention that a metric on $X$ is a function $X \times X \to [0, \infty)$. Some authors allow $d(x, y)$ to be $\infty$, in which case the answers to the first and third points become yes and no respectively.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks a lot, but could you provide some references or theorems where to find "intrinsic metric is necessarily path-connected" and your argument for the second seems to generalise to "no finite metric space can be length metric space" (right ?), but is the answer for the second always yes if the space is inifinite (or at least spaces with more than one point) ?

Comment: You need to look at the specific definition you have been given and think about how it applies if the space is not path-connected. Some texts (like the Wikipedia page you link to) are unclear about this. If allow spaces that are not path-connected, then the most reasonable thing to do is to set $d(x, y) = \infty$ if there is no path between $x$ and $y$, but then you are not working to the usual convention for what a metric is.

Comment: The problem is easy once you unwind the defs : since the distance between two points is the infimum of the length of rectifiable curves connecting them, if there are no curves joining them (thus no _rectifiable_ curves), the distance is $\infty$. A metric space is usually required to have $d<+\infty$, the answer follows since $X$ is path connected: yes for 3, no for 1 and yes unless $X$ is a singleton for 2 by continuity of $d$. If you don't require $d<+\infty$ in your def of a metric space, every two-points space $\{x,y\}$ with $d(x,y)=\infty$ shows the answer is no for 2,3 and yes for 1